# Fill data in XML from another XML file dynamically (Java)

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml file where I would like to fill in values from another xml file. For example, if I have `data.xml`:

```
<Data>
    <Person>
        <Name>neby</Name>
        <Phone>
            <Home>5553456789</Home>
            <Mobile>5559879876</Mobile>
        </Phone>
    </Person>
</Data>
```

I want to fill in `test.xml` like this (Data taken from the above file):

```
<Test>
    <Name>${Name}</Name>
    <Number>${Home}</Number>
</Test>
```

In my Java program, I create XML files during runtime. I would like to give a file name, "pass" it to `test.xml`, have `test.xml` read it, and fill in the text.

Is there a way to do this?

---

<strike>Am I doing it correctly? All I get is the encoding.</strike> Never mind, I got it to work. Using the `data.xml` from above.

MyXSL.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Data/Person">
            <Test>
                <Name><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></Name>
                <Number><xsl:value-of select="Home"/></Number>
            </Test>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Code:

```
try {
    File stylesheet = new File("MyXSL.xsl");
    File dataFile = new File("data.xml");

    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder().parse(dataFile);

    StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet); 
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(stringWriter));

    System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());

} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

<strike>Output: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`</strike>

What am I doing wrong? Above code works.

Comment: This is what XSLT was born for.

Comment: Never heard of XSLT. I'll look it up. If you can give a guide, it would be helpful as well. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Google it.  It's XML style transformations.  Convert one stream to another.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about XSLT! I got it to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create XSLT and then something like that (very simple from oracle java tuts):

```
// ...
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult; 
// ... 

public class Stylizer {
    // ...
    public static void main (String argv[]) {
        // ...
        try {
            File stylesheet = new File(argv[0]);
            File datafile = new File(argv[1]);

            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = builder.parse(datafile);
            // ...
            StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet); 
            Transformer transformer = Factory.newTransformer(stylesource);
        }
    }
}
```

All informations and step-by-step guide to create XSLT and this sample app is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html).

Comment: Thanks, can you look at my code in the OP? I'm not getting the expected output.

Comment: Hi, sorry i was out :) I am happy that its work for you